# Featured image size in ADMIN panel?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to be entirely clear about this, what I'd like to do is change the size of the featured image thumbnail on the ADMIN panel, not on the front end.

I'm building a WP-admin theme, and I need to make the featured image larger on the back end.

It seems, featured images in the edit-post screen always spit out at 266x148px, ideally I'd like them to be actual size. 
I've searched around and can't find any hooks or functions that'd let me do this, but if anyone knows how, it's the people on here.

Comment: Once this happened to me as a bug (images showing in actual size rather than resized in the Featured Image meta box). And it was not nice, they were blowing out of the window viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `'admin_post_thumbnail_html'` and replace the `img` element with a new one in the size you need.

Everything else will get messy and might lead to side effects.

- Filtering `image_downsize` while watching for a size of `266×266` might affect images that are not meant to be shown in the metabox.
- Changing the size for `post-thumbnail` temporary is not easy, because there are no safe points to start and end such a filter.

Comment: Are you saying it's better not to do it?

Comment: No, I just listed two other ways and why I think they aren’t better.

Comment: Ah ok. But does filtering it allow me to have the size as auto?

Comment: I can figure out how to change the html in the box, but not the image itself. add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_image_instruction');
function add_featured_image_instruction( $content ) {
    return $content .= '<p>This is the featured image</p>';
}

Comment: I would also like to do this, here's my related question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160900/resize-admin-featured-image-thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

Starting in [WordPress 4.4](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_size/), a new filter was introduced, `admin_post_thumbnail_size`, which allows for modifying the display size of the post thumbnail image in the Featured Image meta box.

> When a theme adds ‘post-thumbnail’ support, a special ‘post-thumbnail’ image size is registered, which differs from the ‘thumbnail’ image size managed via the Settings > Media screen.

We can use this filter to alter the `post-thumbnail` size (266 x 266 px) and modify it to use the default `thumbnail` size (150 x 15 px) instead.

```php
/**
 * Change Display Size of Featured Image Thumbnail in WordPress Admin Dashboard
 */
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_size', function ( $size, $thumbnail_id, $post ) {
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    $result = array_search( 'thumbnail', $sizes );

    $size = is_numeric( $result ) ? $sizes[ $result ] : array( 100, 100 );

    return $size;
}, 10, 3 );
```

A specific size (e.g., 100 x 100 px) can also be specified or set as a fallback in case the [intermediate thumbnail size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_intermediate_image_sizes/) isn't available.

Comment: Please, do not duplicate answers. Write answers _specific_ to a question: Adapt, change, solve the problem. If you believe that a question is a duplicate, flag the question instead of duplicating answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
/**
 * step 1   define custom image size
 *
 *          either plan to use 'full' (returns the size of the image you uploaded)
 *          OR define our custom image size so we can call one of those instead
 *          of the system defined default 'post-thumbnail'
 *
 *          Remainder of this example assumes using 'full'
 *          no need to define custom a custom image size
 *          so remove the following add_image_size() line (and thereby skip step 1).
 */
//add_image_size( 'admin-post-thumbnail', 846, 288, true );

/**
 * step 2   replace the meta box with ours, for standard post type only
 *
 *          set our own callback and move it into the larger main column
 *
 *          Note the image, even in full size, won't ever have greater width than
 *          the current column width as CSS and modern admin panel make the image
 *          elements responsive to the column width.
 */
 add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'wpse104670_move_meta_box');

function wpse104670_move_meta_box(){
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'), 'wpse104670_post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'low');
}

// step 3   custom callback to call our functional replacement for _wp_post_thumbnail_html for post type only
function wpse104670_post_thumbnail_meta_box( $post ) {
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
    echo wpse104670_wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id, $post->ID );
}

/**
 * step 4   replace _wp_post_thumbnail_html with our version that calls 'full'
 *          (or e.g. 'admin-post-thumbnail' if custom)
 *          instead of the default 'post-thumbnail'
 *
 *          We could do more here, like adjust the content width variable, but
 *          not entirely necessary as custom image size we defined will
 *          handle most of it and admin section has responsive CSS keeping image
 *          from ever exceeding column width.
 */
function wpse104670_wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id = null, $post = null ) {
    global $content_width, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $post               = get_post( $post );
    $post_type_object   = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    $set_thumbnail_link = '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="%s" href="%s" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">%s</a></p>';
    $upload_iframe_src  = get_upload_iframe_src( 'image', $post->ID );

    $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link,
        esc_attr( $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image ),
        esc_url( $upload_iframe_src ),
        esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image )
    );

    if ( $thumbnail_id && get_post( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
        $old_content_width = $content_width;
        $content_width = 266;
        if ( !isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['full'] ) )    // use 'full' for system defined fullsize image OR use our custom image size instead of 'post-thumbnail'
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array( $content_width, $content_width ) );
        else
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'full' ); // use 'full' for system defined fullsize image OR use our custom image size instead of 'post-thumbnail'
        if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
            $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link,
                esc_attr( $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image ),
                esc_url( $upload_iframe_src ),
                $thumbnail_html
            );
            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->remove_featured_image ) . '</a></p>';
        }
        $content_width = $old_content_width;
    }

    /**
     * Filter the admin post thumbnail HTML markup to return.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param string $content Admin post thumbnail HTML markup.
     * @param int    $post_id Post ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', $content, $post->ID );
}
```